# Add custom price to item checkout summary Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout-page, cart-items

Product sale price is custom (different from price-saleprice). Now i want to show row total based on Original mrp(Mrp*qty). Its displaying row total based on custom (sale price * qty).  I did below to achieve this
Created   **di.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
    <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="[company]\[module]\Model\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
</type>
</config>
```

namespace [company][module]\Model\Plugin;

```
class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
{

    $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){

        $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
        $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteId);
        $originalRowTotal = $quote->getOriginalPriceRowTotal();

        $items[$i]['original_row_total'] = $originalRowTotal;
    }
    $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
    return $result;
}

}
```

[company]/[module]/view/frontend/web/js/checkout/summary/items/details/subtotal.js

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total'
],
function (viewModel) {
    "use strict";
    return viewModel.extend({
        defaults: {
            displayArea: 'after_details',
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details/subtotal'
        },
        getValue: function(quoteItem) {
            return this.getFormattedPrice(quoteItem.original_row_total);
        }
    });
}
);
```

I am getting the value right on proceed to checkout but when i go to next step payment and review that value is going to 0.And form payment review to back to shipping step its again going to 0.
[image: row total]
[image: row total is zero]

Comment: I think this might have a helpful answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191723/48243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ConfigProviderPlugin 
{

  /**
    *@var checkoutSession
    */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
    *Constructor
    * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
    */
    public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession)
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {
        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
        foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
          $quoteItem = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemById($item['item_id']);
          $result['quoteItemData'][$index]['original_row_total'] = $quoteItem->getOriginalPriceRowTotal();
        }
       return $result;
    }
}
```

I just replace configProvidePlugin class with above class.

Comment: How do I fetch this data in Subtotal.js?

Answer (score 1):

Just to Add Shekhar Suman  Answer didn't work for me but certainly put me in the right path so Here is my changes to the `ConfigProviderPlugin`:

```
class ConfigProviderPlugin
{
    /**
     *@var checkoutSession
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     *Constructor
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession)
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {
        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
        foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
            $quoteItem = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemById($item['item_id']);
            $result['totalsData']['items'][$index]['original_row_total'] = $quoteItem->getProduct()->getPrice();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

In case anyone stumble on this with the above changes I was able to get original price which in my case I had special price and I need to display the regular price too in summary so it's similar display to product page. 
[image]

Checkout summary block now looks like:
[image]