# getItemById($itemId) for Magento Quote Model not working as expected in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, model, quote, bug, quoteitem

Here is my code, where I'm calling Quote model file and `getItemById` function.

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
    ) {
        $this->quote = $quote;
    }

$itemId = "Quote Item ID";
$data = $this->quote->getItemById($itemId);
```

Above code returns `FALSE` - **even there are 65 Quote Items are exists!**

---

So I checked the **Magento core** method of `getItemById` in -

> /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php

```
     /**
     * Retrieve item model object by item identifier
     *
     * @param   int $itemId
     * @return  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item|false
     */
    public function getItemById($itemId)
    {
        foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
            if ($item->getId() == $itemId) {
                return $item;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

If I print the `$this->getItemsCollection()->getData()` then it returns the **65 Item arrays**.

But As Magento passing directly the **collection object** `$this->getItemsCollection()` in `foreach`

> So It's **not going in-side the foreach loop** which is **expected** result.

Is it a Magento bug or I am doing something wrong ?

---

**Edited**

Issue is still open for Magento Quote model file.

```
/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php
```

As Rohan Hapani's answer we're getting data from `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item` As for now.

But Magento's get **getItemById** still needs to be fixed.

> /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php

```
/**
 * Retrieve item model object by item identifier
 *
 * @param   int $itemId
 * @return  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item|false
 */
public function getItemById($itemId)
{
    foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        if ($item->getId() == $itemId) {
            return $item;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

So open for the solutions :)

Comment: Do you have quote id?

Comment: No, I have Quote Item ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this below code :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item
 */
protected $_itemModel;

public function __construct(
    .........
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $itemModel
    .........
)
{
    .........
    $this->_itemModel = $itemModel;
    .........
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $itemId = "Quote Item ID";
    $this->_itemModel->load($itemId);
}
```

Comment: But still we need to check Why Magento's Quote model function is not working!

Comment: I suppose you are not loading the right Quote object (it is normal if you don't have quote_id)

Comment: No, It is. Please check the /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php file.

Comment: I mean that $this->quote in your code. It is just the injected object in constructor? without loading any id? If that's the case, that object will provide the method, but it won't content any item

Comment: This was the actual case :) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256705/magento-2-rest-sku-to-items-on-cart-totals-api-response-is-not-available-how

Comment: Happy to Help !! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of injecting **\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote** class in constructor, try injecting **\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session** and then

```
$quote = $this->_session->getQuote();
```

This assumes your code is working with a frontend active checkout session

Comment: Let me check @Raul

Comment: Not working, returning false

Comment: mmm I assume you are using an existing item_id instead of "Quote Item ID" text, right?

Comment: Yes yes of-course

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: No Raul can't use session As I am using it for API purpose

Comment: In that case, Rohan Hapani answer should be most valid approach